# Exclude from wildcard (*) using find

Tags: bash, find

I have a command in bashscript that will find the files from a wildcard folder name and count it from that wildcard folder we have a test folder that I want to exclude from count.

Here is my command

```
echo $(date "+%b %_d")
echo "$today"
sr_today=$(find /mnt/data/project_data/web_collab/mailbox/*/sr_pdf/*.pdf -type f -ls | grep "$today" | wc -l)
```

In the mailbox folder there are folders named

`000000`
`111111`
`222222`
`333333`
`so on...`

I want to exclude `000000` from that `find` command. Is that possible? Any tips?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please describe in more detail what are you trying to do with that `find` command?

Comment: I'm curious, why do `echo $(date "+%b %_d")` instead of `date "+%b %_d"`

Comment: And why do `find /mnt/data/project_data/web_collab/mailbox/*/sr_pdf/*.pdf -type f -ls` instead of `ls /mnt/data/project_data/web_collab/mailbox/*/sr_pdf/*.pdf` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if you're going to be using a long path like that, it's best to give it its own variable name. Makes the code easier to read, makes sure you use the same name everywhere without typos, and makes it easier to change if you need.

```
MAILBOX=/mnt/data/project_data/web_collab/mailbox
```

Try this if there's less than a few hundred pdf files to contend with:

```
echo "${MAILBOX}"/*/sr_pdf/*.pdf | grep -v /00000/ | grep "$today" | wc -l
```

And if you want a more general solution, do this:

```
find "${MAILBOX}" -path '*/sr_pdf/*.pdf' | grep -v /00000/ | grep "$today" | wc -l
```

Comment: echo should change with find

Comment: How many files are we talking about? If it's less than a couple hundred or so, echo should work just fine. But I'll update my answer two.

Comment: @EdwardFalk Hundreds of folder and hundreds of files

Comment: But it will not go beyond 300

Answer (score 6):

Using GNU `find`:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

dir='/mnt/data/project_data/web_collab/mailbox/'

sr_today=$(find "$dir" \
             ! -path '*/000000/*' \
             -newermt '12am today' \
             -ipath '*/sr_pdf/*.pdf' |
           wc -l)
```

- GNU `find`'s `-newermt` option understands the same date formats as GNU `date -d` and `touch -d`.  See `man find` and search for `-newerXY` for details.
- the final `-ipath` predicate is case-insensitive, so it will match *.PDF, *.pDf, etc.  Unfortunately, it's also case-insensitive when matching the sr_pdf directory.  If there are, e.g., SR_PDF subdirectories that you don't want to match, and you're sure that all `.pdf` file extensions are lowercase, change `-ipath` to `-path`.

  Or, for case-sensitive `sr_pdf` path match and case-insensitive `*.pdf` file match, replace that `-ipath` line with:

```sh
      -path '*/sr_pdf/*' \
      -iname '*.pdf' |
```

Comment: Actually, I like this solution better than mine in some ways. However, -newermt is not portable (BSD doesn't have it.)